# Is there a common tcp/ip protocol decoder?

Tags: netty, tcp

My situation is:

1. I have a website, it is an iot platform
2. I use netty to make a tcp server
3. users can add devices and define tcp/ip protocols for their devices, for example,1,2,3,4\n is a protocol use line delimiter.
4. the server should decode their protocols and show data on the website

Now, my question is, is there a common open source tcp/ip protocol decoder , or how i can define a decoder by myself ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the protocol you may need to write your own decoder. Netty itself contains multiple decoder implementations and some of them may just be what you need but this is really impossible to tell without more details. General speaking if you need to write your own decoder for TCP based protocols you usually start by either extending `ByteToMessageDecoder` or `ReplayingDecoder`.